# How to load Raw Pixel Bitmap on SDL?

Tags: c++, sdl

Currently I use bmp files for an SDL app, but I want to hide them to distribute my exe. I thought moving them as raw bytes into header files was a good way, since the BMP are very simple Black&White patterns.

Am not sure if this is possible by using SDL only, but so far I fail to load a simple pattern of bits.

```
// data.h    
const unsigned char rawPixels[] =
{
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
};


// main.cpp
...
SDL_RWops *pixelsWop = SDL_RWFromConstMem((const unsigned char *)rawPixels, sizeof(rawPixels));
SDL_Surface *pixelsSurface = SDL_LoadBMP_RW(pixelsWop, 1);
SDL_BlitSurface(pixelsSurface, NULL, NULL, NULL);
...
```

I only get an empty surface from the SDL_LoadBMP_RW call, maybe the array should contain proper BMP header, etc. Could someone point out if that's the problem? 
Is there another way of loading this?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why this is not working is because your data does not represent a bitmap, it is raw pixel data. If you want to see what a raw bitmap would look like, simply create one in paint and open it in an Hex Editor, you will see the header and then the actual pixel data.

I would advise simply creating a `SDL_Surface` using the dimensions you want and then either modify the pixel access method from [this page](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/Pixel_Access) to take the raw data or call `putpixel` for each and every of your pixels (if this is only for test purposes).

Depending on a few factors all of your pixels will not be a contiguous array of values in memory, you will need to take into account the `SDL_Surface`'s `pitch` and `bpp` (Bytes per pixel).  In your case I assume it is a 8 bits (1 byte) pixels?  In this case, it could be pretty easy to fill your `pixels` data row by row, moving your row pointer of `pitch` each time.

You will likely find [this document](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlpixelformat.html) interesting too.

Comment: what's the point of pitch?  I mean why would pitch be different than the width in the image?  I know using SSE/AVX it helps so have the width a multiple of 4 or 8 so then the pitch and width can be different but that's the only example I know of.  I'm wondering if there are more common examples?

Comment: This thread has a lot of explanations about the pitch :) http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=4544&sid=dd7f398958ed1ddd4cbbae9a903bcd5b

Comment: Thank you!  That's exactly the type of discussion I was looking for.